# The syntax highlighting language for [cocoa-touch] is incorrect

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

For cocoa-touch (wiki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocoa-touch/info))

1. The current language tag ("lang-C") is completely incorrect
2. If (for some reason) have to have a language tag on cocoa-touch, it is either swift or obj-C
3. It seems, it should not have a language override, it's just a library. The language will I guess be properly set by the other tags of the question (e.g. iOS, mac, swift, objc, etc. etc.)

All current Q&A tagged with both [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) and [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) are broken, e.g.

[image]

Comment: Footnote for googlers:  add <!-- language: swift --> in your answer to fix the woe manually

Comment: Sounds about right but I’m no iOS dev. Side note: all questions that are tagged with [tag:cocoa-touch] *but not [tag:objective-c]* will have broken highlighting when we remove the setting. You may want to preempt this by editing them, see [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcocoa-touch%5D+-%5Bobjective-c%5D+-%5Bswift%5D+is%3Aq). And holy mother of... that’s about *16 thousand posts*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters !! they all have *iOS* (or Mac) !!  Right?  :O

Comment: Maybe then @MartijnPieters it *is* better to go with Swift (or I guess obj-c).  ("lang-c" just makes no sense at all, it's a typo)

Comment: Aha, it’s all down to history: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317603/should-there-be-clearer-usage-guidance-for-ios-iphone-cocoa-touch-obje

Comment: There is no `lang-obj-c` highlighter. The [tag:objective-c] tag also uses `lang-c`; it is *close enough*.

Comment: Wait, *iOS* is set to have no code language !  wth ?!

Comment: Same problem as with setting a preference on cocoa-touch: there is no single iOS programming language in posts tagged with iOS.

Comment: ?  It is impossible to "make iOS" without Swift  :)  certainly, if someone asks the rare obj-c question they'd add that tag and override. (or - whatever - who cares?  Who cares about a 1% problem when the situation is currently "just broken" ??  :O)   ios and indeed cocoa should surely just be "swift", to make the SO site (overwhelmingly) work better.  This strikes me as hair-splitting (to what end??) so I'll step back!  But thanks a million for letting me know the in-answer tag to add to make that sucker work, cheers !

Comment: No, iOS is used for far more than just Swift questions. And we can’t just throw posts that predate Swift under the bus. Just tag those posts with Swift.

Comment: "No, iOS is used for far more than just Swift questions."  Hmm, I don't really understand that logic:  If there's an iOS question, and, it happens to include some code {sure, many questions may not include code}, that code will be Swift, so the code-look-option on "iOS" should surely be ....  "Swift".  I guess?  (i) ok, regarding iOS questions, which do include some code: a tiny number will include c, objc, c++, java, etc. but (I assume) we couldn't care less about tiny numbers, (ii) regarding historic questions, ie those from before objC or before Swift ..

Comment: .. I mean, I guess if the site policy is to cater for questions before objc, before swift, before .. punch cards!  :) .. I mean, well, that's that.

Comment: So bearing all that in mind !  i can't see ***any reason*** cocoa-touch should have "lang-c".  It just doesn't make any sense.  It should have none, or (until apple changes again), Swift. Cheers!

Comment: How about just unsetting the language override for [cocoa-touch]?

Comment: has nothing, at all, been done with this after two years ?